# Get array of posts without content from WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I use following code to get list of posts

```
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($the_query->have_posts()) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    //work with post
}
```

in this case I get the content and other stuff for each post in the array. But I don't need content, it can be rather big. Can I exclude content from the result array to improve performance?

Comment: Did you try wpdb to fetch data. visit https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: No, I didn't, but maybe this is the best option. Put it as an answer and I will set it as the best. Maybe it will be helpful for someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wpdb to fetch data. visit: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

May this help.